# How can I use the $match operator twice in a single mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two models:

```
const ClientRequest = new mongoose.Schema({
   sourceLanguage: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    customer: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client'
    }
}
```

and

```
const Client = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    web: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
}
```

And I need to find all `requests` filtered by `sourceLanguage` and `name`.
I'm using this query:

```
const requests = await ClientRequest.aggregate([
            {$match: {
                "sourceLanguage.symbol": "EN-GB"}
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "clients",
                    localField: "customer",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "clients"
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "clients.name": filters.clientFilter,
                }
            }
        ])
```

But it returns empty array. If I remove one of the `$match` it works. But how can I use both of the filters at the same time in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different approaches, but as sometimes it happens, the simpliest way worked out:

```
const requests = await ClientRequest.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "clients",
                    localField: "customer",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "customer" // I used the same name to replace the Id with the unwinded object
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    "customer.name": filters.clientFilter,
                    "sourceLanguage.symbol": "EN-GB" // or any other filter
                }
            },
            {$unwind: "$customer"} // here I just unwind from array to an object
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const requests = await ClientRequest.aggregate([
            {$match: {
                "sourceLanguage": "EN-GB",
                 "customer": ObjectId("5d933c4b8dd2942a17fca425")
               }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "clients",
                    localField: "customer",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "clients"
                }
            },

        ])
```

Comment: I don't have customer's `id`. I get `name` as filter for customer

Comment: Yes, and that is why I want to find a way to filter by `name` which is a reference to another model in a single query with other filter.

Comment: just use this query and populate and get clients name easy way